# Can't get initial state, error: Type '{ workouts: Workout[]; } | null' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am trying to display the initial state of my application on the page.
But when I do a for loop over the state data, I am getting an error `Object is possibly 'null'.`

Several steps forward: the `*ngFor` looks like this now `*ngFor="let workout of (workouts | async).workouts"` .
And when I delete `.workouts` the error turns to be `Type '{ workouts: Workout[]; } | null' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'`

So I assume that my application can't fetch the initial state for some reason. I checked the models, all types of data are correct.
I also Googled for this: [Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716660/type-object-is-not-assignable-to-type-ngiterableany-null-undefined)
But it seems like I am doing everything right.

**Now the code:**

workout.model.ts

```
import { Exercise } from "./exercise.model"

export interface Workout {
  name: string,
  exercises: Exercise[]
}
```

exercise.model.ts

```
export interface Exercise {
  name: string,
  completed: boolean
}
```

actions.ts

```
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store"
import { Workout } from "../models/workout.model"

export const ADD_WORKOUT       = 'ADD_WORKOUT'
export const REMOVE_WORKOUT    = 'REMOVE_WORKOUT'
export const UPDATE_WORKOUT    = 'UPDATE_WORKOUT'

export class AddWorkout implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_WORKOUT

  constructor(public payload: Workout) {}
}

export type Actions = AddWorkout
```

reducer.ts

```
import * as WorkoutActions from "../actions/tasks.actions"

const initialState = {
  workouts: [{
    name: "Day 1",
    exercises: [{
      name: "push-up",
      completed: false
    }]
  }]
}

export function workoutsReducer(state = initialState, action: WorkoutActions.Actions) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case WorkoutActions.ADD_WORKOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        workouts: [...state.workouts, action.payload]
       };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      workoutsList: workoutsReducer
    } as ActionReducerMap<any,any>)
  ],
```

workouts-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Workout } from '../models/workout.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-workouts-list',
  templateUrl: './workouts-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workouts-list.component.scss']
})
export class WorkoutsListComponent implements OnInit {

  workouts!: Observable<{workouts: Workout[]}>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<{workoutsList: {workouts: Workout[]}}>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.workouts = this.store.select('workoutsList')
  }

}
```

workouts-list.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let workout of (workouts | async).workouts">
  <div>{{workout.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid getting the `Object is possibly 'null'.` error by using the [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html).

Try using it after workouts in the for loop.

Comment: Actually this helped. And I even can assume why :) I'm just concerned that it should have been working without this tirck

Comment: I think you can disable it. Check `strictNullChecks` in your `compilerOptions`